# installing the barcode scanner plugin for iOS phonegap

Tags: ios4, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm looking to install the the phonegap barcode scanner plugin but I'm not quite sure where to start. I have already coded an app on the android using the same plugin so I'm looking to port this same app over to iOS. I was following a very easy tutorial for the android version so it was all straightforward and most of the hard work was done for me. But for the iOS version, it's not quite the same case.

Can I get some help confirming if my steps are correct? Also, since this plugin supports both android and iOS, my app should have no problem being ported correct?

right now, I'm thinking of doing the following:
1.http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20iOS%20using%20Xcode%204
this would get a template app running for the iOS

2.follow the install plugins direction on the github page

3.import main.js and index.html from my android code

4.success

is it as simple as I've described it? Am I missing something?